# When to use service layer in laravel mvc framework

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns

I have same code for my api and web

So I try to use **Service layer** in my project

I read a lot of open source project made with Laravel and there is no services in them and I'm confused **why**?

**UPDATE**

I figure out these way that must library use

1-Use job for business logic https://github.com/akaunting/akaunting/tree/master/app/Jobs

2-Use trait as @Hamelraj suggested

So are these ways a good replacement for **Service layer**?

Comment: try this - https://www.develodesign.co.uk/news/laravel-traits-what-are-traits-and-how-to-create-a-laravel-trait/

Answer (score 0):

**Everything is a service.**

In context of Laravel, generating form, form validation, generating csrf token, Authentication, Routing, Broadcasting, Managing event, Laravel app instance itself etc. are services. There are some services referred to above Laravel needs to prepare or fulfill a request and there are others that Laravel bootstrapped for later uses for developers.

Any other frameworks like Laravel does not know what else services need in future for its developers. Otherwise, it can make needless complexity. So they implement a design principle called **SOA** (Service Oriented Architecture). So that developers can add services when they need and Laravel takes them into account. That means you can use them in the app. This is totally the point to catch.

Hope you understand!

Comment: I understood you well, But still I'm confused, how many way I have to prevent duplicate code in web and api? How to approach this? I think I cant use service provider in laravel for this, So I have to create a Service layer or what?

Comment: Well, can you show me some code examples where you think that duplicate code is happening?

Comment: for example I have a lot of code for registering user, add data default data to user, create some records related to user.  So I can do it with `Service layer` like this `$userService->create($request)` and put all my code in service. But there is no library use that and I wonder why?

Comment: Laravel has Service Provider what you're calling Service Layer is actually SOA. These all 3 are same. So use it. See the doc there https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/providers

Comment: I understood laravel service provider, But I think it's not a place to put business logic. Service provider are providing some feature for whole apps, Is not a place to call it in controller ( for example after validation )

Comment: Well, akaunting does not do anything that is better than SOA. Rather, in some places the didn't maintain dependency injection. However you may do so using laravel's service provider. You separate your services according to their domain attaching namespaces. Then bind them with your app so that you can call any like `App::make('your_service')` in your controller or other way. Yes they can be better place for establishing business logic. Thanks

Comment: Oh! `trait` can never be used for these cases.